# MVC ValidationMessageFor not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following in my view:

```
     <fieldset>
        <legend>User Registration</legend>            
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UsrName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UsrName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UsrName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Pwd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Pwd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Pwd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReEnterPwd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ReEnterPwd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ReEnterPwd)
        </div>            
       <fieldset>
         <legend>Location</legend>
           <span id="locationDiv"> 
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Location, "Loc1")  @Html.Label("Loc1")
           &nbsp;&nbsp; 
           </span>
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Location, "Loc2") @Html.Label("Loc2")               
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Location)
        </fieldset>         

         <fieldset>
         <legend>Role</legend>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Role, "User") @Html.Label("User")
           &nbsp;&nbsp; @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Role, "Admin") @Html.Label("Admin")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Role)
         </fieldset>  

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Register User" />
        </p> 
    </fieldset>
```

Even if I don't have all the fields filled, it still goes to the controller even though they are all required. I thought

```
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor
```

was supposed to prevent that.

```
    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UsrName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Must have a minimum length of 5.")]
    public string Pwd { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Re-enter Password")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Must have a minimum length of 5.")]
    [Compare("Pwd", ErrorMessage = "The password and re-entered password do not match.")]
    public string ReEnterPwd { get; set; }
```

Comment: couple questions: does your form have "@Html.ValidationSummary(true" ?

Comment: in web.config: <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
???

Comment: And confirm that you have attached the jquery validation script files... Maybe jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js file is missing?

Comment: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Just thought I'd also mention that ValidateMessageFor does not actually cause validation, it merely displays error messages... The Model Binder invokes this when the form is submitted, and jQuery.Validate causes it to be done before the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You must include the following scripts in the view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Bahman, the user never showed us their view. are you sure they're missing those libraries?

Comment: Worked for me, somehow I was missing the lines.

Comment: thanks for this!, I just added the unobtrusive.js in my bundleconfig :-)

Comment: This worked for me. I added into the BundleConfig and render in any of the layout.

Answer (score 3):

I had to include the JQuery Validation bundle at the bottom of my view in the scripts section.

I noticed this exists in all the baked in views for login and authentication but needs to be manually added to your custom views.

Example

```
    @section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```