# MVC5 Razor ValidationMessageFor triggered on hidden, not-used div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a model which defines a series of boolean items as well as a series of properties of type `StentProperties` among other data types.  [Note that these are not marked/annotated as required]

```
[DisplayName("Drug eluting balloon (DEB)")]
[UIHint("YesNo")]
public bool DrugElutingBalloon { get; set; }
[DisplayName("DEB Properties")]
public StentProperties DrugElutingBalloonProperties { get; set; }
```

The problem I am facing is a weird behavior on the view when creating a new record.  The `StentProperties` are only displayed when the respective bool item is true (via a radio button) - these are all hiding in divs.  The problem occurs whenever I click `Create`.  The  `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DrugElutingBalloonProperties)` is triggered and doesn't let me post unless I enter information for this specific element.  The other `StentProperties` do not trigger the validation... this leaves me clueless.

Thoughts?

Comment: Found the problem.  It turns out that on the `[httppost]Create(...)` the Model Binder was including this specific `StentProperty` (included it a couple of nights ago for whatever reason and those strings get so long I kept missing it).  The following solution helped me realize the cause of my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488737/mvc-validationmessagefor-not-working-properly @PatBurke

Comment: Hi, welcome! If you found an answer to your problem, feel free to answer your own question! And don't forget to mark it as answer so that the question can be "resolved".

Comment: Thanks @Vish I can't mark it as resolved for another 7 hours... am new to the forum and don't have enough reputation points :S

Comment: Agree - I meant "when you are able to" :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It turns out that on the [httppost]Create(...) the Model Binder was including this specific StentProperty (included it a couple of nights ago for whatever reason and those strings get so long I kept missing it). The following solution helped me realize the cause of my problem: stackoverflow.com/questions/14488737/… @PatBurke –